# HTTP Deadline exceeded waiting for python Google Cloud Endpoints on python client localhost

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-python-client, httpexception

I want to build a python client to talk to my python Google Cloud Endpoints API.  My simple HelloWorld example is suffering from an HTTPException in the python client and I can't figure out why.

I've setup simple examples as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315131/consuming-gae-endpoints-with-a-python-client) extremely helpful thread.  The GAE Endpoints API is running on localhost:8080 with no problems - I can successfully access it in the API Explorer.  Before I added the offending `service = build()` line, my simple client ran fine on localhost:8080.

When trying to get the client to talk to the endpoints API, I get the following error:

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/gae_override/httplib.py", line 526, in getresponse
raise HTTPException(str(e))
HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/helloworldendpoints/v1/rest?userIp=%3A%3A1
```

I've tried extending the http deadline.  Not only did that not help, but such a simple first call on localhost should not be exceeding a default 5s deadline.  I've also tried accessing the discovery URL directly within a browser and that works fine, too.

Here is my simple code.  First the client, main.py:

```
import webapp2
import os
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build

http = httplib2.Http()

# HTTPException happens on the following line:
# Note that I am using http, not https
service = build("helloworldendpoints", "v1", http=http, 
  discoveryServiceUrl=("http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/{api}/{apiVersion}/rest"))

# result = service.resource().method([parameters]).execute()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write("Hey, this is working!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', MainPage)],
    debug=True)
```

Here's the Hello World endpoint, helloworld.py:

```
"""Hello World API implemented using Google Cloud Endpoints.

Contains declarations of endpoint, endpoint methods,
as well as the ProtoRPC message class and container required
for endpoint method definition.
"""
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote


# If the request contains path or querystring arguments,
# you cannot use a simple Message class.
# Instead, you must use a ResourceContainer class
REQUEST_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    name=messages.StringField(1),
)


package = 'Hello'


class Hello(messages.Message):
    """String that stores a message."""
    greeting = messages.StringField(1)


@endpoints.api(name='helloworldendpoints', version='v1')
class HelloWorldApi(remote.Service):
    """Helloworld API v1."""

    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, Hello,
      path = "sayHello", http_method='GET', name = "sayHello")
    def say_hello(self, request):
      return Hello(greeting="Hello World")

    @endpoints.method(REQUEST_CONTAINER, Hello,
      path = "sayHelloByName", http_method='GET', name = "sayHelloByName")
    def say_hello_by_name(self, request):
      greet = "Hello {}".format(request.name)
      return Hello(greeting=greet)

api = endpoints.api_server([HelloWorldApi])
```

Finally, here is my app.yaml file:

```
application: <<my web client id removed for stack overflow>>
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: helloworld.api
  secure: always

# catchall - must come last!
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always


libraries:

- name: endpoints
  version: latest

- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

Why am I getting an HTTP Deadline Exceeded and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `main.py` you forgot to add some variables to your discovery service url string, or you just copied the code here without it. By the looks of it you were probably suppose to use the format string method.

```
"http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/{api}/{apiVersion}/rest".format(api='helloworldendpoints', apiVersion="v1")
```

By looking at the logs you'll probably see something like this:

```
INFO     2015-11-19 18:44:51,562 module.py:794] default: "GET /HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2015-11-19 18:44:51,595 module.py:794] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 3109
INFO     2015-11-19 18:44:52,110 module.py:794] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/helloworldendpoints/v1/rest?userIp=127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3719
```

It's timing out first and then "working".

Move the service discovery request inside the request handler:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        service = build("helloworldendpoints", "v1",
                    http=http,
                    discoveryServiceUrl=("http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/{api}/{apiVersion}/rest")
                    .format(api='helloworldendpoints', apiVersion='v1'))
```

Comment: How did the log spit out the right URL if it wasn't already formatted with {api} and {apiVersion}?  Nevertheless, the log's ip (`rest?userIp=%3A%3A1`) does indicate perhaps the ip address is screwed up?  Strange, your formatting trick did not work - despite specifying the userIP as 127.0.0.1, the log still comes back with the exact same timeout message with the same strange IP

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said you probably copied it wrong, but I had to add it. This is really an abnormal devserver behaviour. Quite intriguing. Try going to http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/helloworldendpoints/v1/rest?userIp=127.0.0.1 Do you get a proper response?

Comment: Yes, I get the proper response with that link.  I also get the identical proper response if I cut/paste the log's error's URL, the one with the `rest?userIp=%3A%3A1`.  Direct browser interaction works fine.  I cut/paste your code right into my code and still got the timeout.  You can see why this would be frustrating!

Comment: I even set the timeout to 40 second on `http = httplib2.Http(timeout=40)` so it's probably the case of some leaky abstraction.